# Android - get results from db based on user location

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, location

I'm building an app that shows certain locations in a list that are inserted into a database. Right now I have a php server that posts the results as json and everything works fine.

Now I'm going to add this location part to it. It is supposed to (when the app starts) get the user's location and show these locations based on this location.

My question is, what would be the best way to accomplish this? Measure the distance between user and location in server, or just fetch all the results to my Java code and then see what locations are suitable (within reach). Which way is faster for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not gone tell which is best or faster approach - Decide yourself.

First approach :-
If i were you, I would send the current location to server and then make all the calculation like calculating the distance between user location and all the available locations in the server. Based on the constraints(Less than 5 miles or km) i would send only those locations as response.

Second approach:-
You send all the locations as response but calculating distance on mobile end will slow down the things at user interface.

why do you have to get all the useless data on rest service calls when you can have filtered data from server.

I hope this helps you in deciding.

Comment: But my concern is that would it be awfully slow to check for each distance separately. Would it be possible to limit the query someway?

Comment: how would you calculate distance between latitude ,longitude using any google map api or just calculate straight distance between two set of latitude and longitude points ? both ways would be slow and when number of locations increase it gone be awful slow. so i suggest you to do it in server end.